# Handling redirect Response from a Restful or JAX-RS web service

Tags: java, rest, gwt, resteasy

A typical restful call from GWT (using RestyGWT) looks like this:

```
LoginService.Util.getService().login("FACEBOOK", new MethodCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Method method, Void response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {

    }
});
```

Although the call might respond onSuccess, the **redirect** response is not processed. Which the server side redirect looks like this:

```
return Response.seeOther(new URI(url)).build();
```

What is the proper way of handling redirect from request either made through `RequestBuilder` or `RestyGWT`?

Comment: If I change the login method to return the URL string to re-direct to, Facebook complains that the request did not come from the domain. So Window.Localation.replace is not a viable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial, [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html), And try this,

```
// Send request to server and catch any errors.
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

try {
    Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                updateTable(JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText()));
            } else {
                displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText() + ")");
            }
        }
    });
} catch (RequestException e) {
    displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
response.sendRedirect("http://10.62.229.57:8080/birt/");
```

I use for **redirect response** in Jax-rs web service.